# Writing a java.lang.Object in XSD schema

Tags: java, xsd

I have an XSD with attributes as boolean,integers and element as an arraylist like below,

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:tns="http://www.template.com/project/v1/Repository"
            targetNamespace="http://www.template.com/project/v1/Repository"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
            version="1.0"
            xml:lang="en">

            <xsd:complexType name="Response">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="records" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:Record" />
            </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="pageSize"              type="xsd:integer"   default="-1" />
                <xsd:attribute name="pageNumber"            type="xsd:integer"   default="1" />
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="Record">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="column" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"  type="tns:Column" />
            </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:complexType name="Column">
            <xsd:attribute name="columnId" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:attribute name="columnValue" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:complexType>
```

Now am trying to add an element with list of object (`List<Object>`). I cannot add Object class in type. So how can i add Object class in XSD.

```
            <xsd:element name="jsonrecords" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type=" "  </xsd:element>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<xsd:element name="jsonrecords" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:anySimpleType" />
```

it will generate something  like

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType")
protected List<Object> jsonrecords;
```

Comment: Though it generated an List<Object> jsonrecord i could not map from VO to dto(generated from xjc compilation). java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element

Answer (score 0):

See the mapping chart here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnazq.html, yo can use xsd:anySimpleType that should translate into java.lang.Object